# Defining a matrix based on given data

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning, sparse-matrix

I have this dataset which is of the form

```
    14     2    -1
    18     2    -1
    63    58    -1
    69    58    -1
   125   126    -1
   127   126    -1
   128   126    -1
   129   126    -1
   143   131    -1
   188   184    -1
```

I want to define a matrix C which is MxM which consist of 1 in `C[u,u] = C[v,v] = 1` and `C[u,v] = C[v,u] = -1` for each entry `(u,v,-1)` in my dataset, how can I do this in matlab? the matrix C can be sparse because M is very large, it could be up to 1 million.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the sparse matrix for your data which is called `A` using `sparse`:

```
  M = 1e6; % given value
  A = [A; A(:, [2 1 3]); [1:M].' [1:M].' ones(M,1)];    %(u,v) = (v,u) = -1, and (u , u) = 1 
  C = sparse(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),M,M);
```

In the above if:

```
A = 
[14     2    -1
 18     2    -1
 63    58    -1
 69    58    -1
125   126    -1
127   126    -1
128   126    -1
129   126    -1
143   131    -1
188   184    -1];
```

we add `(i,i)` into the `A` with value 1 and then create a sparse matrix from these values.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but your solution seem to assume that both (u, v) and (v, u) are in data set which is not correct, we might have (u,v) or (v, u) or both of them in dataset and none of them could be in data set too.

Comment: @Hadiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii Nope. " but your solution seem to assume that both (u, v) and (v, u) are in data set" I didn't do that! Just add `(i,i)` to your data as you said in the question.

Comment: I guess that I have said it unclear, the data set is not a symmetric matrix, it is asymmetric

Comment: @Hadiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii Ok. For mine is asymmetric!

Comment: I quote the sentence in original paper that I am reading maybe I am getting it wrong: "We introduce one sparse auxiliary matrix C, which is defined for any distrust relations (u,w) in Phi (the dataset) with all elements equal to zero except C[u,u] = C[w,w] = 1 and C[u,w] = C[w,u] = -1"

Comment: @Hadiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii now, my code is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If your original list is a matrix `A`:

```
A = [14     2    -1
    18     2    -1
    63    58    -1
    69    58    -1
   125   126    -1
   127   126    -1
   128   126    -1
   129   126    -1
   143   131    -1
   188   184    -1]

M = max(A(:)); % or whatever size you want, this is the minimum size
% matrix with ones on the diagonal.
C = diag(ones(M,1)); % you can cast it with sparse() if you want to
% set coordinates to -1 or whatever is in A(:,3)
C(sub2ind(size(C), A(:,1), A(:,2))) = A(:,3);
```

Comment: It actually gives the exact same result as OMGs code (just not as sparse, but that's easily adjusted)

Comment: Just do `full(C)` and you'll get the same result as the previous answer.